# MySQL cannot read error file

Tags: mysql, permissions, pid, error-log

Important info first: I am on OS X 10.7.5 and trying to work with the newest version of MySQL.

I try to start the MySQL server and I've been getting the error code

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/<insert my
username here>.local.pid).
```

I found a website that says that this just says, in essence "Hey, there's an error here and it's in the error file."

Trouble is, I can't seem to actually read the !*%?!# error file. I used `sudo chmod u+x` to alter the file to give me the permission to open it (I couldn't before), but it's a .exe now and there isn't actually a program to open it to read it, even though the "kind", as the finder calls it, is actually a document.

I have tried easily 20+ tricks to try and grant the permissions correctly, and still I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I'm assuming the actual answer is in the error log. How do I open it? And then what do I do when I've actually opened the log?

Comment: chmod +r is the command to make readable +x is for executable. From other parts of the question I would suggest that you need to work through some unix tutorials

Comment: What do you mean "*it's a .exe now*"?  What file are you talking about?  The error log?

Comment: @Mark, quite probably. I am very new to programming/computers and am entirely self-taught. So, do I just redo it with u+r or is there a way to undo what I did with u+x?

Comment: @eggyal, yup. The error log is now an executable file.

Comment: Just chmod +r but you need to study more to answer the rest of the question, if you are having issues as you show here you are likely to have other errors.

Comment: There is a difference between "*a .exe*" (which means, to me at least, that the filename ends with those four characters) and "*an executable file*" (which means different things depending on the operating system).  Whilst on Windows there is some overlap, on OS X there is none.

Comment: @Mark, at the same time, I still need to fix this in order to continue working so I can make money so I can have time in the evenings to work through unix tutorials. Also, now I don't have permission to look at the file again.

Comment: It will be quicker to learn the issues then try to do the work